# Completey manual way to update to .NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

MY company has a strict "no software installations allowed" policy. We are currently using VS2010 and MVC 2 that come with it when it was installed. We would like to upgrade to MVC 3 but because of the policy we can not use the standard MVC 3 tools installer nor do we have nuget for downlaoding or installing packages.

So is there any way to manually add/upgrade our projects to MVC 3 so we make use of the latest and greatest stuff? Is it as simple as getting the dll file and registering it to the GAC?

Comment: Oh, hell... I suppose you don't have administrative rights to your development machine either. Our developers all have MSDN subscriptions and a development computer that is isolated from the Internet, so it can't catch a cold. We each have a different, heavily locked down machine for Internet, email, word documents, etc.

Comment: To answer the question you asked, no, I don't think you can install ASP.NET MVC 3 without the installer, because there is tooling that goes into Visual Studio when you install it.

Comment: Completely off base and I suppose inflammatory, but the only possible response I could muster after reading your question is "Find a new job."

Comment: `no software installations allowed` - How did you get your VS2010 installed then? If the policy changed then they need to upgrade the environment. If you decided on your own that the upgrade needs to take place, then that really isn't a change in policy.

Comment: @Chris - Lock down is happening everywhere. No Admin, No Exe's, No Zips. You cant escape it, especially in certain 'sensitive info' industries. The worst bit is - you want admin rights so bad, but when you get them you realise its way more trouble than its worth, like removing Option Explicit from VB6 projects!

Comment: It's not the lockdown that's the problem. A developer without modern tools is handcuffed to the post. If you're going to waste administrative effort (IMO) treating your devs like children, then it's your administrative responsibility to ensure / provide access to the best (and most recent) tools available to ensure optimal developer efficiency.

Comment: What about using a VM to do work on? They're fast enough on modern systems. Or just use your own laptop :)

Comment: We have approved software lists. Somethings can be installed but it has to be done by the overlords. Its possible for us to request software for the approved list but it takes incredibly long for them to get to it and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best you can do I believe.

There is no completely , 100% manual way I believe. Still have to move things around and it sounds like you may have restriction issues but here it is [Source:](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading)

To manually upgrade an existing ASP.NET MVC 2 application to version 3, do the following:

Create a new empty ASP.NET MVC 3 project on your computer. This project will contain some files that are required for the upgrade.
Copy the following files from the ASP.NET MVC 3 project into the corresponding location of your ASP.NET MVC 2 project. You'll need to update any references to the jQuery library to account for the new filename ( jQuery-1.5.1.js):

```
/Views/Web.config
/packages.config
/scripts/*.js
/Content/themes/*.*
```

Copy the packages folder in the root of the empty ASP.NET MVC 3 project solution into the root of your solution, which is in the directory where the solution’s .sln file is located.
If your ASP.NET MVC 2 project contains any areas, copy the /Views/Web.config file to the Views folder of each area.
In both Web.config files in the ASP.NET MVC 2 project, globally search and replace the ASP.NET MVC version. Find the following:
System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0
Replace it with the following:

System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0
In Solution Explorer, delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc (which points to the DLL from version 2), then add a reference to System.Web.Mvc (v3.0.0.0).
Add a reference to System.Web.WebPages.dll and System.Web.Helpers.dll. These assemblies are located in the following folders:
%ProgramFiles%\ Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies
%ProgramFiles%\ Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and select Unload Project. Then right-click the project name again and select Edit ProjectName.csproj.
Locate the ProjectTypeGuids element and replace {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325} with {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}.
Save the changes, right-click the project, and then select Reload Project.
In the application’s root Web.config file, add the following settings to the assemblies section.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

If the project references any third-party libraries that are compiled using ASP.NET MVC 2, add the following highlighted bindingRedirect element to the Web.config file in the application root under the configuration section:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
           publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: I would **not** suggest doing this without making a copy first.

Comment: Whether manual, automatic or no upgrade at all there always needs to be a backup copy ofcourse.

Comment: How do I make the "Empty MVC 3 Project?" We only have MVC 2 right now. I assume that we can get our hands on the necessary dll files and stuff but what would we need to grab?

Comment: You'll still need to get MVC3 dlls and possible other files on your and server system ofcourse. Does this help? : http://forums.asp.net/t/1770112.aspx/1